# can textures and bumpmaps be "baked" into a single texture?

Tags: texturing, performance

In Blender it seems bump maps tend to take longer to render, so I was wondering if it was possible to merge those into an image such as a UV map.
is there a way to do this or a way to make bumpmaps render quicker?

Comment: You mean modify an image texture with the shading from a bump map?

Comment: yes- I want to keep the appearance, but reduce the need to constantly re-calculate the sides even if they don't change

Comment: You might be able to combine the baked images is some way, but I don't think it will work for animation.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer what you are asking, but you may want to check out [this video](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2014/07/10/shader-forge-material-speed-boost/) on CG Cookie on speeding up bump map rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a full bake

Note: this does not work for animation